# Trying to use VDataTable from labs but getting 'VDataTable' is not exported by node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.mjs error

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I am migrating an old Vue project to Vue3 + Vuetify3 + Vite. I am stuck on the VDataTable which is available via [Vuetify Labs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/).

I have followed instructions for importing the VDataTable component in vuetify.js:

```
    import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
    import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
    import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
    import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'
    
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
      components : {
        ...components,
        VDataTable,
      },
      directives,
    });
    export default vuetify;
```

But when I try to use `<v-data-table>` in my MyTable component, I get the following error in the Console (vite dev mode) and the table is not displayed:

> SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vuetify_components.js?v=56a024d1' does not provide an export named 'VDataTable' (at MyTable.vue?t=1678324759732:1:199)

I am using Vite for the build and the Vuetify3Resolver. Not sure this is relevant - isn't the syntax above importing the component directly?

Also, running a `vite build` I get the following error:

```
'VDataTable' is not exported by node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.mjs, imported by src/components/MyTable.vue
file: C:/dev/tpw/src/components/MyTable.vue:3:9
1: /* unplugin-vue-components disabled */import { VWindow as __unplugin_components_4 } from 'vuetify/components';
2: import { VWindowItem as __unplugin_components_3 } from 'vuetify/components';     
3: import { VDataTable as __unplugin_components_2 } from 'vuetify/components';      
            ^
```

What am I missing?

I have reproduced the issue here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-unrx3c?file=src/vuetify.js

Comment: I believe that Unplugin tries to find the a-la-carte components inside `vuetify/components` but VDataTable is not there - so you may need to import it manually in all your components where you need it instead of expecting it to be automatically registered globally like the other Vuetify components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by changing the plugin I use for component import. Instead of using `unplugin-vue-components` (and the Vuetify3Resolver) I instead added [vite-plugin-vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin) which is apparently the recommended way as per the [Vuetify Docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/). This makes the manual import of VDataTable  work correctly.

It simplifies vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import vuetify from 'vite-plugin-vuetify';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vuetify({ autoImport: true }), // Enabled by default
  ],
});
```

And also simplifies vuetify.js as you don't need any * imports since the vite-plugin-vuetify automatically imports components as required:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components : {
    VDataTable,
  },
});
export default vuetify;
```

Comment: I couldn't get to VDataTable to render properly when doing `yarn build` but it works in `yarn dev`. Seems to be missing CSS. Any ideas?

Comment: You saved the DAY. Thanks